# jersey ResponseBuilder filename encoding

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, character-encoding, jersey

In javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder, when I set filename, with polish (german, french, etc.) national characters, it changes file name before response is sent to client:

```
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file);
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=żółty.txt");
```

After this, file is being downloaded as "-óBty.txt". How to fix this?

EDIT:
Whole application works properly with UTF-8 (json content contains polish characters for example). Only http headers doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. According to [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) one should not use non-ASCII characters in the header, but use url-encoded values instead. There is special grammar for this case:

```
String encodedFileName = URLEncoder.encode(file.getName(), "UTF-8");
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + encodedFileName);
```